# How can I show a form on a second screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-monitors

I am creating a C# form application. I wanted to show the initial form on a second screen. I want to open the other form pages on the first screen. There is a resolution difference between two screens. How can I show the initial form on the second screen and the other five forms on the main screen?

Answer (score 4):

In matter of window positioning there are no "two screens" but just one "working area".
Meaning if you have two FullHD screens next to each other you have a working area of 3840x1080 (minus some for taskbar and such).
If you then place a window at `Left = 200` and `Top = 100` it will be placed 200 pixels to the left side of the left screen and if you place it at `Left = 2120` and `Top = 100` it will be placed at the same position on the right screen.
And for all that to work you need to use `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual`.

Comment: First of all, I developed the application in 1366x768 resolution computer.I want to show the starting form of the application on a second screen with a resolution of 3840x2160.I want to continue showing the other forms of the application on the first screen, which is the main computer screen.
I have to write a c# code to do this @ChrFin

Comment: @berkaydombaycı Still the same rule applies. In your case the working area will likely be something like 5206x2160 (if the screens are aligned next  to each other) -> if the 1366x768 screen is left anything above `Left = 1366` will start on the second screen...

Comment: thanx a lot for your helps @ChrFin

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method, hope it helps you:

```
public void MaximizeToMonitor(Form frm, int monitorIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            Screen screen = Screen.AllScreens[monitorIndex];
            if(screen != null)
            {
                frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                var workingArea = screen.WorkingArea;
                frm.Left = workingArea.Left + 10;
                frm.Top = workingArea.Top + 10;
                frm.Width = workingArea.Width + 10;
                frm.Height = workingArea.Height + 10;
                frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Monitor does not exists. {Environment.NewLine}{ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot to share this code with me.ı run this code, 
I got an error message. message is " a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or method".
what should i do to overcome this problem.
Thank you for your help @ShadyOverflow

Comment: the error message is explaining it self, i guess you putted the method in the namespace directly, instead, you should put the method inside some class.

Comment: thanx a lot for your helps @ShadyOverflow